# Quelle est la signification de l'expression « genre que + sujet + verbe + au sens négatif » ?

Tags: sens, québec

J'ai trouvé une expression comme : « genre que + sujet + verbe + au sens négatif ».

**Par exemple:**

« Genre que je ne fais jamais quelque chose. »

Je ne sais pas le sens de « genre que » ainsi que je ne peux pas le trouver sur l'internet. J'ai entendu cette phrase dans un contexte québécois.

---

I found an expression in the form: "genre que + subject + verb + in the negative."

**For example:**

« Genre que je ne fais jamais quelque chose. »

I do not know the meaning of "genre que" and I cannot find it on the internet as well. I heard this expression in a Quebec French context. An English equivalent would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cette expression signifie *comme si*.  Dans l'usage que j'ai constaté, elle n'est pas suivie uniquement de propositions négatives.

Elle me semble plutôt d'un registre familier, si pas populaire. Je doute que l'expression soit propre au Québec (mais elle est y peut-être plus commune et moins marquée sociologiquement), je suis persuadé de l'avoir entendue dans la bouche de personnes qui à ma connaissance n'ont pas de liens avec cette région.

*Genre que j'ai des millions à claquer.*  signifie donc *Comme si je pouvais gaspiller de l'argent.*

On entend aussi simplement *genre* plutôt que *genre que* dans le même type de construction, avec le même sens. (Signalé par @Random).

Comment: A noter que c'est une tournure de phrase trèèès familière.

Comment: @MakorDal, nous sommes d'accord, c'est pourquoi j'ai qualifié son registre de _familier si pas populaire_.

Comment: En France, "genre que" ne me parle pas du tout. Par contre, "Genre j'ai jamais fait qqch" est utilisé (je pense que ça a le même sens).

Comment: @Random, j'ai entendu les deux.  (J'ajoute une note sur le sujet).

Answer (score 2):

On parle généralement de diverses formes d'approximations ou d'une vague idée de catégorisation, présentée comme explication, et parfois élevée au rang de prototype, ou encore d'un truc purement fonctionnel marquant l'hésitation, évoquant la possibilité, ou servant à moduler l'intensité d'un propos ou à orienter le discours. L'*Académie française* note certains des usages de *genre* à la manière d'un adverbe dans une rubrique sur les [*emplois fautifs*](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/dire-ne-pas-dire/recherche?titre=genre) ; on l'identifie à un *usage relâché* supplantant *style*. On a un exemple en tête de phrase où on dit que le genre dans « *genre, tu le connais vraiment ?* » signifierait un truc exclamatif tel *Pas possible !*, *Sans blague*, *Blague à part* etc.

Par ailleurs, l'utilisation, plus courante, par extension de [*genre de*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/genre) en français relève souvent de l'approximation (« *Un colossal fragment de cathédrale inachevée en granit, par Herrera, dans le genre de St Pierre de Rome.* » T. Gautier), mais ce ne sont pas à mon avis toutes les manières d'approximer qui participent de cet usage :

> — Combien en voulez-vous ? 
>  — J'en voudrais **genre** dix... (à peu près, une dizaine)

Je ne vois pas à quel emploi *genre* ou de *comme* ça correspondrait en français. *Dans le genre* de dix ? Ce serait un long détour pour dire simplement *à peu près*. Ici l'*Académie* a un exemple avec [genre + heure] et on rend avec *vers/environ*, l'approximation.<sup>1</sup>

---

Étant surtout familier avec le français québécois, j'ai déjà entendu diverses constructions avec *genre* (et « comme », incidemment), dont les suivantes :

> 1—*La maison a plus genre 40 ans que 20.* [davantage (à peu près) un que l'autre]
>   2—*Genre (qu')il devrait venir avec nous autres. Genre (que) sa jambe serait pas cassée.* [Il devrait probablement venir avec nous ; sa jambe ne serait probablement pas cassée]
>   3—*Je l'ai fait genre mal*. [plutôt... mal... à certains égards]
>   4—*E[lle é]tait là genre, « je [ne] l[e]'crois pas », pis
>   j'ai dit genre « non, vraiment ! ».* [elle a dit un truc comme...]
>   5—*Genre, pourquoi tu m'as pas écrit ? [enfin/en fait/dis donc...]
>
>   6—La musique était, genre, vraiment bonne, t[u]'sai[s] [ce que je] veux dire ?*  [,disons/je dirais/euh...,]

Ces emplois ne sont pas tous égaux et certains me semblent encore plus étranges que ceux relevés par l'*Académie* et je ne peux dire s'il s'agit des mêmes influences. Ces exemples, traduits d'un [dictionnaire usuel](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/like?s=t) de langue anglaise (ex. 16, 17, 18, 21, 25) en substituant *genre* à *like*, illustrent à mon avis que l'usage au Québec (sinon en France) suit de près plusieurs formulations avec [*like*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82966/like-as-nonstandard-adverb-and-informal-interjection-for-the-approximation-fu) en tant qu'*adverbe*, *conjonction*, et *interjection*. À moins de penser à *like* en anglais, et donc de substituer un calque à un autre, [*comme*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme) ne suffit pas plus que *genre* à rendre le sens de tous ces emplois en français. Dans tous les cas à mon avis c'est vraiment fort peu soigné quand on ne peut réellement y substituer *dans le genre de/du genre de*, tout en respectant la syntaxe et la sémantique de la langue française. Je me suis brièvement entretenu avec une personne plus âgée mais partageant mon sociolecte (sud-ouest, grand centre) et dont la particularité est de ne pas parler anglais : soit on ne comprend pas l'expression (1-6), soit on y trouve *genre* superflu ou inattendu ; ça n'autorise cependant aucune conclusion.

---

Dans l'exemple en question, ça semble être surtout fonctionnel, pour introduire ou mettre l'accent sur ce qui suit, un peu comme si on disait *en résumé/normalement* + je ne [fais jamais quelque chose]. Le locuteur répond ici à une question par une approximation (sur une norme de conduite qui est la sienne). Ce peut être un usage relâché à l'oral, une forme d'exclamation ; à mon avis c'est très marqué, surtout en début de phrase, et peu expressif, que ce discours à demi-mot, et ce pourrait être un calque ou une influence des emplois de *like* en langue anglaise (où c'est parfaitement expressif).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Le *DHLF/Rey* note un emploi à la mode dans le sens de *sorte*, *type* avec le « *mec genre bobo* » et on parle d'un autre emploi similaire avec le nom en fin de phrase mais on ne précise pas (*genre bobo mec* ou *genre mec bobo* ?, avec *être*, en attribution). Intéressant développement en langue française, mais ça n'a rien à voir avec la question... Voir aussi cette question au sujet de certains emplois de [*like*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82966) en anglais.</sub>