# “He was like” vs “il était genre” similarities and differences

Tags: anglais, usage, oral, comparaison-de-langues

What are the similarities and differences between the Americanism 'He was like...' And the French expression 'Il était genre...'? They both introduce citations.

Comment: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/17943/quelle-est-la-signification-de-lexpression-genre-que-sujet-verbe-au-sen

Comment: Getting so few hits (272 and 393, respectively) is adequate confirmation that "[j'étais **comme** OMG](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22j%27%C3%A9tais+comme+OMG%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)" and "[j'étais **genre** OMG](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22j%27%C3%A9tais+comme+OMG%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22j%27%C3%A9tais+genre+OMG%22)" are both non-standard, but I think this is the usage that you’re asking about, no?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the two are pretty much exactly the same and can be used interchangeably. They're both just filler words to give the speaker an extra second to think about what he/she is going to say.

> "I was like, 10 miles from home when..."
>
> "J'étais genre, à 10 kilomètres de chez moi lorsque..."

Comment: Sorry, but that is not what I meant. "To be like" is a single verb in the US used to introduce a quote. For example: He was like: "Wow!". Might one say in French: Il était genre: "Waaaouh!".

Answer (score 2):

They mean the same thing, the only difference is on the language level: *genre* in this situation, e.g.

> Il a genre trois ans
>   He's like, three years old

is in French pretty informal (maybe in English too, I don't know)

This structure doesn't necessarily introduce a *citation*, but any form of *complement* (adjective, proposition, noun, and any citation would be reported speech); it mostly adds an overtone of *vagueness* rather than exact information.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself well. Take as an example the US expression TO BE LIKE, which acts as a verb that introduces a quote: "He was like: 'I can't stand it.'" Might this translate into French as: "Il était genre: "Je ne peux pas le supporter"?

Comment: B.Scholl: Ah! You should have made that clearer! Please add this precise context to your question.

Comment: well, didn't I answer that too? I'm confused now

Answer (score 2):

To *be [like](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=like&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)* is an informal way of saying *to utter/to say* (*AHDotEL*). The word [genre](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/genre/36604?q=genre#36555) ([2](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/genre)) is not part of any idiom using the verb [*être*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre/31549/locution) which would yield a similar meaning in French. *Être du genre humain* for instance, would mean *to belong to*. The *Académie française* [discusses](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/dire-ne-pas-dire/recherche?titre=genre) it indirectly and labels this sort of usage as an "emploi fautif" (incorrect use) : « *Il m’a répondu genre j’en sais rien*, phrase d’où toute syntaxe a disparu, pourrait se dire *Il m’a répondu à peu près, approximativement, en gros qu’il n’en savait rien.* ». One can only speculate as to what the *Académie* would say about the syntax here seeing there is not even the verb *répondre/dire* in the sentence you provided; worst, there is obfuscation from a verb (*être*) which is not even part of an idiom here and which doesn't mean *to say/utter* in any way, shape or form.

---

Ways to express "*il était genre*"+quote which are more consistent with the French language :

> Il a dit un truc du/dans le genre : « [citation] ».
>   Il a dit un truc comme : « [citation] ».
>   Il a dit un truc similaire à : « [citation] ».

---

The difference is that this is correct, if informal, English, whereas it is most likely incorrect usage in French as the syntax is off.

Comment: Fortunaately English does not have an Académie to tell us how to speak our own language!

Answer (score 0):

**En français moyen :**

> Il était du style : "..."
>
> Il était du genre : "..."

**Plus construit:**

> Il était du style à dire/affirmer/... : "..."
>
> Il était du genre à dire/affirmer/... : "..."

**Langue parlée:**

> Il était genre/style: "..."

Comment: You are doing here a mistranslation as "il était, genre, fou de rage" means: "he was like, completely mad" whereas "il était du genre fou de rage" means "he has a mad nature"