# How to say "Even" as in "We can't even cook a little bit"?

Tags: grammaire, expressions

How do you express the word "even" as in:

> I can't even do that!'

Also, a bit out of topic, how do you express the word "like" as in:

> Like seriously!
>   Like honestly, I can't stand them even a bit

Comment: You should ask 2 seperate questions for this. About "like", For 2nd question, you may have a look at [this question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18005/he-was-like-vs-il-%C3%A9tait-genre-similarities-and-differences/18006#18006) maybe. Also, you should give more details about the meaning of "like" in your example. Since most of us are not native english, it may be difficult to answer if we don't know what it means... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time the word "même" will be used:

"I can't even do that !" -> "Je ne peux même pas faire ça !"

For your second example, the "even a bit" does not translates well. The most idiomatic I can think of is:

"Like honestly, I can't stand them even a bit" -> "Genre, sérieusement, je ne peux pas les blairer." (very familiar)

But if you need to stick to the fidelity of the translation you could say:

"Like honestly, I can't stand them even a bit" -> "Genre, sérieusement, je ne peux pas les supporter, pas même un tout petit peu."

Answer (score 1):

*I can't even do that* = *Je ne peux même pas faire ça*

So in this context you translate *even* with *même*.

*Like seriously* = *mais serieux* (a bit familiar) OR *mais serieusement*

It is not as common as the structure "like [adverb]" in english.