# Utilisation du mot "Genre" dans le parler québécois

Tags: expressions, québec

J'ai  très souvent entendu des Québecois utiliser le mot « genre ». J'ai posé la question à une personne qui l'utilisait régulièrement et elle m'a dit « c'est comme *like* en anglais ».

Cependant, je pense ne pas encore comprendre son utilisation. Quand j'essaie de le dire... les gens pensent que j'ai dit quelque chose de bizarre ou ils doivent réfléchir pour comprendre ce que j'ai dit.

Quelles sont les nuances du mot « genre » et pourquoi ne pas utiliser le mot « comme » au lieu de « genre » ?

Answer (score 9):

Tout d'abord je signale que le mot est aussi employé **dans l'hexagone** avec le sens du *like* anglais. Mais à une bien moins grande échelle qu'au Québec. C'est plutôt du parler « [djeun](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/djeun) »,   même si des plus âgés l'emploient aussi.

Commençons par [ce fil twitter](https://twitter.com/gonzague/status/1150067762854862848) d'un jeune parisien qui s'intitule « C'est genre galère de pas savoir faire une phrase sans dire "genre" ? »
On y voit dès le haut du fil deux emplois différents du mot :

- Le premier où on pourrait remplacer « genre » par « comme » :

> « Les jeunes c'est genre un peu la génération de demain »

- Le deuxième où c'est plutôt l'équivalent de « par exemple » :

> « Moi, le truc qui, genre, me choque, c'est le mot "iconique" en fait. »

Voir aussi ce [fil de blog](https://blog.okapi.fr/blablaclub/et-toi-tu-parles-lado-4797.html) d'une discussion entre collégiens :  « Et toi, tu parles l'ado ? » :

- > ben non la première fois que g entendu sa c t dans mon collège Ils deviennent populaire Pck tt le monde les dits et que si ya ôtât genre 3 personnes qui le disait eh bah les autres le diraient pas non plus sa marche

(Ici pour moi ça veut dire « environ ».)

- > Chez nous c'est plutôt swag... Batar ou des trucs, genre, wesh...

(Pour moi cette utilisation fait partie de la ponctuation  (voir plus bas)).

- > Qu’en pensent tes parents ? Utilises-tu ce langage avec eux ? Utilisent-ils ce langage ?Ils ne disent trop rien tant que ça reste correcte ...Non ils ne l'utilisent pas ou des fois pour rigoler en disant "nan mais genre les meufs là !"

(Ici pour moi ça veut dire « par exemple ».)

Une recherche dans un moteur de recherche montre que le mot est beaucoup plus utilisé **au Québec**. Je ne donnerai qu'un seul exemple, ils sont nombreux, trouvé sur un blog qui s'intitule « [québé-chisme](https://quebechisme.wordpress.com/2007/12/05/guidoune-pitoune-poupoune-nounoune-coucoune-toutoune-doudoune-chouchoune-minoune-moumoune/) » :

> – « Qu’est-ce que ça veut dire guidoune ?
>   – Euf… c’est genre une fille mal vue, facile…
>   – Ben, c’est quoi la différence avec pitoune ?
>   – Euf… pitoune c’est plus comme une belle fille qui s’habille trop sexy…
>   – C’est pas une poupoune ca?

Pour finir  voici un extrait du [mémoire de maîtrise](http://www.archipel.uqam.ca/2051/1/M9152.pdf) d'un étudiant de l'université du Québéc, *Description du lexique appartenant au vernaculaire des jeunes adultes de 17 à 25 ans habitant dans les quartiers est de Montréal* qui récapitule les emplois du mot en québécois :

> Genre: [3âr] adv. Début des années 90'.
>   1. Marqueur de relation. Syn. Comme, environ, par exemple. *J'ai eu genre 33 % à mon exam.* *J'ai genre perdu mon billet.*
>   2. Ponctuation à l'oral; ce mot peut remplacer la virgule, le point, le point d'exclamation, le point d'interrogation. Il peut se placer au début, au milieu ou à la fin de la phrase.
>   Lorsqu'il est placé en début de phrase, *genre* sera suivi en général de la conjonction que. *Genre que c'est pas mal cool. C'est genre pas mal cool.C'est pas mal cool genre.*

Et en fin d'item il donne la définition du mot « genre » relevée dans deux dictionnaires :

> ./ DQF, «langage des jeunes (fin des années 90) dans le genre, du genre, quelque chose comme [structure semblable en argot français: 'ce type est genre un peu lourd' » ; PQ, « par exemple », « environ [... ] dans le langage des jeunes ».<sup>1</sup>

Voir aussi les réponses à cette question [Quelle est la signification de l'expression « genre que + sujet + verbe + au sens négatif » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/17943/358) auxquelles j'aurais certainement renvoyé si je les avais vues avant. (Merci @suiiurisesse).

---

<sup>1</sup> DQF : Dictionnaire québécois français de Lionel Meney (1999) ;  PQ : Petit Guide du parler québécois de Mario Bélanger (ouvrage non scientifique) (1997)

Comment: @suiiurisesse Au temps pour moi ! J'aurais dû vérifier qu'une question très proche avait été posée....

Comment: Réf. [ceci](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/18007). Ta réponse présente les équivalents plus clairement et c'est bien mieux étayé à mon avis. Ce qui m'inquiète c'est que l'algo. du site n'a pas su faire apparaître l'autre contenu en question liée malgré le fait qu'on a « genre » au titre et le mot-clé _Québec_ dans les deux cas alors je me demande comment l'algorithme fait...

Answer (score 1):

C'est assez récent comme expression et surtout utilisé par les jeunes. Le mot peut d’ailleurs être utilisé **avec** ou en remplacement du mot *comme*. Mais principalement, je dirais que *genre* n'a pas vraiment d'utilité dans une phrase, c'est une expression qui permet de ralentir le dialogue et qui est souvent utilisée à outrance au point d'en être dérangeant. Le meilleur parallèle serait effectivement le mot *like* ou l'expression *you know* en anglais ou encore *ano* en japonais.

Quelques exemples :

- "Lui chu genre comme put capable de le sentir" (Lui je ne suis plus capable de le voir/ de lui parler)
- "Faque la j'étais genre ''de kessé tu parle maudit'' ?" (Je lui ai demandé ce qu'il voulait dire)
- "En plus, hier j'étais genre trop fucké" (Hier j'étais dans un état second)
- "Ste band la yé genre trop su'a coche" (Ce groupe de musique est vraiment bon)
- "C'est comme genre vraiment trop dla marde" (C'est vraiment mauvais)

En fait, même sans faire la (traduction) les phrases peuvent parfaitement se dire en joual québecois sans y ajouter genre. Quant à savoir pourquoi, les gens ne comprennent pas, j'imagine que ça dépend de l’interlocuteur auquel vous vous adressez et de la formulation / niveau lexical de la phrase.

Comment: Ce n'est pas vraiment récent, J'ai genre 40 ans et on le disait à l'école primaire il y a genre 30 ans!

Comment: Haha j'ai dans la 30 aine mais je m'identifie encore comme un "jeune" et oui on l’utilisait aussi à mon époque, j'ai peut-être pas été assez précis dans ma tranche d'âge. Dison que ma mère ne l'utilisait pas (67 ans) mais je suis peut-être dans l'erreur, genre, en ce qui concerne le côté nouveauté.

Answer (score 0):

Je ne trouve pas d'information sur cette forme ajoutée en fin de phrase mais je comprends que c'est un terme d'origine récente. 
Je crois qu'il faut ajouter ce terme lorsque ce qui précède n'est qu'un à peu près, quelque chose que l'on a dit mais qui ne représente pas exactement ce dont il s'agit et qui n'est en fin de compte qu'un exemple de ce que ce pourrait être véritablement. Comme ce que l'on ajoutait par le passé dans ces circonstances c'était des expressions plus longues, typiquement « quelque chose dans ce genre-là », « ce genre de chose » et qu'en anglais les locuteurs faisaient de même avec des expressions telles que « something like that », « or something like that », lorsque les gens qui parlaient anglais ont commencé à raccourir ces expressions en « like » les utilisateurs du français ont pensé eux aussi à raccourcir l'équivalent et il se trouve que quelqu'un à pensé à utiliser «  genre », qui est resté. Il se pourrait que l'inverse soit arrivé, mais j'en doute.

Answer (score 0):

La seule règle d'usage fonctionelle à garder en tête pour bien utiliser le mot 'genre' de la façon slang décrite, est que la présence du mot ne change en rien le sens de la phrase.

Ex.:

> Si tu utilise 'comme' ou 'genre' de la bonne façon, tu vas comme genre
>   avoir l'air vraiment détaché et ça te confère un cool factor comme
>   genre full legit.